# Cordova on WP8 - deviceready not fired

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I've developed an application with Cordova, it actually works fine on Android and on iOS.

I want to try it on WP 7/8, but when I launched the app, it seems like the `device ready event` is not fired, so nothing works.

I use Cordova 3.1.0, I read somewhere that it could be cordova that is not loaded in VS2012.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I've found that the Console plugin isn't allowed : 
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. Console

Comment: Like in this thread : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4718

Comment: Any ideas to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was not the deviceready event but the database initialisation.

Cordova database API isn't supported on Windows Phones. So it bug at the start when I init the DB while everything is OK on Android and iOS.